# Three.js, Is it possible to change the pan speed interactively?

Tags: three.js, webgl, pan

I am using OrbitControls to control a 3D model.

I configured the panSpeed to (0.1) to have a slow pan speed, but when I zoom to an object on the scene, this panSpeed (0.1) is very high for that view.

I mean the overall view and object view need different panSpeeds.

How can we interactively change the panSpeed based on the distance to the object? This interactive pan helps to control the scene smoothly.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you answer your question yourself. Use the distance of the camera to your object to set the value for panSpeed. Since you probably want the panSpeed value to decrease as the distance decreases, use something like distance/100 for your panSpeed value.

Comment: I could compute the distance from camera to objects! but I cannot update the panSpeed using controls.update()!! I am using  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container). Any solution to update the panSpeed interactively? Thanks.